# mod_rewrite leads to infinite loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following file which accepts 3 get parameters: v, p, and pp

```
127.0.0.1/archive/index.php
```

within the archive directory I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^v=(\d+) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     &v=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^                   /archive/%1/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)\/?$          /archive/index\.php?v=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The code rewrites **127.0.0.1/archive/2/ -> 127.0.0.1/archive/index.php?v=2**

But when I try to set a 301 to redirect get parameters to the clean URL, an infinite loop incurs. I only need the v parameter to redirect to /archive/x/ from either **/archive/?v=x or /archive/index.php?v=x**

Answer (score 0):

You can have this rule in `/archive/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /archive/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?v=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [L,QSA]
```